# How to Convert System.Drawing.Image to Byte Array?

Tags: vb.net, image, arrays

Hi I'm trying to convert image to byte array to pass it into sql as byte(). Im trying to use Image Converter but it keeps failing

```
Dim converter As New ImageConverter
nRow.Signature = converter.ConvertTo(imgSignature, TypeOf(Byte())
```

the error I keep getting is byte is a type not expression

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The VB.NET TypeOf operator doesn't do what you think it does.  Somewhat confusing perhaps due to the C# `typeof` operator.  The VB.NET equivalent is the GetType() function.  This works fine:

```
Dim converter As New ImageConverter
nRow.Signature = converter.ConvertTo(imgSignature, GetType(Byte()))
```

The type converter uses a MemoryStream to make the conversion, using the PNG image format.

Answer (score 19):

You can use a `MemoryStream`.  By saving the image into a `MemoryStream`, you can get the byte array of data from the image:

```
Dim ms = new MemoryStream()
imgSegnature.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg) ' Use appropriate format here
Dim bytes = ms.ToArray()
```